# Load .svg content in Angular 2 using d3.js

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to use a simple d3.js method `d3.xml` in Angular 2, so I can load the content of an .svg file into my html template. Relevant code from my component bellow:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { D3Service, D3, Selection } from 'd3-ng2-service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'ContentPhotos',
        templateUrl: './content-photos.component.html',
        styleUrls:['./content-photos.component.css'],
    })

    export class ContentPhotosComponent implements OnInit {

      private d3: D3;

      constructor(
        d3Service: D3Service,
      ){
        this.d3 = d3Service.getD3();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        let d3 = this.d3;

        d3.xml(this.layout.url).mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
          if (error) throw error;
          console.log(xml.documentElement);
        });
      }
    }
```

However I can't get this to work in Angular. It says

```
Property 'xml' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/wamp64/www/angular-cli/node_modules/d3-ng2-service/src/bundle-d3"'.
```

As you can see, I use `d3-ng2-service` to load d3 into my app. Can anyone get me unstuck please? Cheers!

Comment: But you have something like `private d3: D3; constructor(element: ElementRef, d3Service: D3Service) { this.d3 = d3Service.getD3(); }` in your Component, right? Please provide a [mcve] or at least all the code relevant to this.

Comment: Thank you @altocumulus, I'm a bit new to SO. I've updated the question with a mcve :)

Comment: UPDATE: Found the source of the problem: 

https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service#scope-of-d3-functionality

The `xml()` is part of d3-request module which "has been omitted as a design choice", if favor of using "the Angular http service for client/server communication".